# How to increase logo size in android studio

Tags: javascript, android-studio, graphical-logo

[Show Screenshot 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WuOK.jpg) In the following screenshot you can see that the marked app's logo looking small and bad quality text than the other near by apps so please guide me how to obtain that size and quality of the picture.

Comment: Screenshot is not visible and share your code as well.

Comment: please check back again. now screenshot has been added.

Comment: You should add the screenshot in the question rather than a link to it. And share your code to show what you have done so far to achieve the desired result and what problem you are facing in doing so.

Comment: To show a image in question stack over flow requires 10 reputation but at this time i have only 7.